# How do I print a list in Trello for offline use?

Tags: trello, printing

I would like to print an entire list in Trello for offline review.  How do can I do this?

Answer (score 14):

I found the *[Board Printer for Trello](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trello-board-printer/jbgpfjbmmlcaicpeimjggdppephemamf)* Google Chrome extension very useful.

> Board Printer for Trello adds the ability to print the cards from your boards on Trello. Printing your cards can make it really easy to manage both a physical and virtual scrum board at the same time.

Comment: Link only answers don't make good answers. What is this application called? (There's no indication in the link). What does it do?

Comment: The extension no longer works

Comment: does not work only part of the contents are printed

Answer (score 6):

The Trello team has released some printing styles so printing a board or card is more legible. Printing a *single* list is not currently possible, nor a planned feature.

Simply use the browser's printing ability to print: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, File → Print, or right click → Print

Answer (score 4):

another good solutions is Trello2html
https://trello.com/b/j2Fj36tT/trello2html-export-and-print-trello-boards

Github project
https://github.com/tianshuo/trello

Comment: So far this is the only good solution I've found; thank you

Answer (score 3):

I've made a web service to print Trello boards in multi-column style:

https://yarosla.github.io/trello-custom-print/

Features:

- choose number of columns (1 to 6)
- select lists to print
- optionally print descriptions, checklists, **custom fields**
- apply markdown formatting

How to use:

1. Give the app permission to read your boards (enable popup windows).
2. Select board to print.
3. Adjust layout and visibility options.
4. Press print button.

About privacy: This is single page web app hosted on GitHub without any server side logic. So don't be afraid your data is intercepted or stored somewhere.

Open source: https://github.com/yarosla/trello-custom-print

Suggestions and feedback welcome.

Comment: Would be super nice to include cover images (yes I know it's open source)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using http://connie-clark.github.io/print-trello/.  I run it as instructed, then since I want it all on a quarter-size sheet, I copy/paste the contents of each list into a pre-formatted Word document that I set up.  I also made a Word macro to delete out some things I don't want, and quickly turn each list into a Word bulleted list.

It would be so nice if this were set up as a Trello option and I didn't have to do all these steps, but this is working for me.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new Trello board and leave it blank ("New_Board")
2. Copy the Trello list you want to print ("List_Copy")
3. Move List_Copy to New_Board
4. Print New_Board
5. Archive List_Copy
6. Proceed at step 2 with any other list you want to print

Answer (score 0):

I found the [Print Friendly & PDF](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/print-friendly-pdf/ohlencieiipommannpdfcmfdpjjmeolj?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) as a solution, you open the card and use the extension to print as a PDF or just print. Worked very well to me.

Answer (score 0):

Before I found the Trello print feature on the Board menu, I simply copied and pasted into a Word doc. Yes, this is a bit tedious but it does allow me to set the formatting up to my preferences which are a bit cleaner than the Trello option. And, I was able to copy and paste checklist from the back of cards under each heading (again, to my prefs). These are options that it would be great for Trello to offer, but until then I'm glad I have a way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Trello's card printing ends up being a hassle. I would suggest trying out [Uzility's](http://uzility.com) card printing system. It's more straightforward. You can [import your cards](https://uzility.com/Imports/) from Trello or another platform, right click on the column you want printed, and it gives you sizing options depending on your preference.

[image: Uzility Card Printing - Right Click Column] 
[image: Choose Card Size For Printing]
[image: Right Click On Page And Print]

Comment: If you are affiliated with the product, please disclose that in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Trello2md](https://github.com/phipsgabler/trello2md) converts JSON exports from Trello to Markdown. The resulting file can then be translated further to other formats such as PDF or HTML using a Markdown converter (like Pandoc).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Butler automation](https://help.trello.com/article/1192-creating-reports-with-butler) to run a Calendar command that sends you the cards in a specific list directly to your **email as a report** every morning. Then you could **print that email**. Here's the pattern I use for the report.

```
every day at 8:00 am
create a report with all cards in list "My Day" using pattern "- [{cardname}]({cardlink}) ({cardlabelnames})"
and send an email notification to "myemail@interwebs" with subject "My Day in Trello" and message "{$report}"
```

Also here's a screenshot of the command set up.

[image: Butler Calendar command set up for report]

A sample screenshot of how the email might look like is provided in the [Trello docs (linking here for completeness)](https://d33v4339jhl8k0.cloudfront.net/docs/assets/545804d8e4b09c5ca72525ce/images/5d4d99420428631e94f93511/file-4REZZ8xjo9.png).